# Is there a way to view the stack during development with Michelson?

Tags: michelson

Is there some kind of debugger tool to view the stack while developing with Michelson (other than try-michelson.com)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dedicated [VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=serokell-io.michelson-debugger).

Answer (score 3):

- Emacs: The OCaml Tezos distribution comes with `michelson-mode` for Emacs that visualizes the stack. For more info, see [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/various.html#environment-for-writing-michelson-contracts).
- Vscode: A michelson mode with stack visualization for vscode can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/kinokasai/vscode-michelson).
- IntelliJ: See this [blog post](https://www.plugin-dev.com/plugins/tezos-michelson/) for information on a IntelliJ plugin that includes stack visualization.

Answer (score 2):

https://smartpy.io/michelson shows the stack while you type along with other information.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it has some useful features. Sorry I can't upvote you, I'm too new apparently.